# HTTP Interceptor send same request twice

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular-httpclient, angular-http-interceptors

I'm using an HTTP interceptor in order to add auth token to requests but when the http client fires the request, this is intercepted and sent twice

This is my HttpClient call

```
  searchProd(query: string, limit?: number): Observable<Product[]> {
    let _limit = limit || 5;
    return this.http.get<Product[]>(`${API_CONST.HOST}/${API_CONST.PRODUCT}?search=${query}&limit=${_limit}`);
  }
```

This is my app.module.ts

```
import { HttpClientModule, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http'; 
import { TokenInterceptor } from './auth/token.interceptor';
....

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    ...
  ],
  imports: [
    ...
  ],
  providers: [
    ApiService,
    AuthGuardService,
    SettingsService,
    {
      provide : HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass : TokenInterceptor,
      multi : true
    }
  ],
  entryComponents: [ ... ],
  bootstrap: [ ... ]
})
```

This is my token.interceptor.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {
  HttpRequest,
  HttpHandler,
  HttpEvent,
  HttpInterceptor,
  HttpResponse,
  HttpErrorResponse
} from '@angular/common/http';
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { AuthGuardService } from './auth-guard.service';
import { API_CONST } from '../services/api/api.service';

@Injectable()
export class TokenInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
  private no_auth_endpoints = [
    `${API_CONST.HOST}/${API_CONST.PRODUCT}`
  ]
  private token = null;
  constructor(public af: AngularFireAuth, private authGuard: AuthGuardService) {
    this.token = authGuard.getToken();
  }
  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    const headersConfig = {
      'Authorization': `Bearer ${this.token}`
    };

    let isAuthEnpoint = true;
    this.no_auth_endpoints.forEach(endpoint => {
      if(request.url.includes(endpoint))
        isAuthEnpoint = false;
    })

    if (!request.headers.has('Authorization') && isAuthEnpoint) {
      const modified = request.clone({
        setHeaders : headersConfig
      });

      return next.handle(modified); //this line is executed twice!
    }
    else {
      return next.handle(request); //this line is executed twice!
    }

  }
}
```

Throught the chrome dev tools i see the same request sent twice in the network tab. During debugging I saw the http request send by searchProd once but when it's intecepted the next.handle() is executed twice. How to fix that in order to send only one request?

EDIT: This is what is shown in network tab

First request
[image: Request 1]

Second request
[image: Request 2]

EDIT2: This is the code where I call the searchProd(string) function.

component.html

```
<mat-form-field class="bottom-search-field">
    <input [formControl]="autoCompleteControl" type="text" placeholder="Aggiungi un prodotto"
      matInput [matAutocomplete]="auto">
    <mat-autocomplete autoActiveFirstOption #auto="matAutocomplete" (optionSelected)="onSelectionChanged($event)">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let item of searchResults | async; let index = index" [value]="item.description | titlecase">
        {{ item.description | titlecase}}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-autocomplete>
  </mat-form-field>
```

component.ts

```
public autoCompleteControl = new FormControl();
...
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.searchResults = this.autoCompleteControl.valueChanges.pipe(
      startWith(''),
      switchMap(value => {
        if (value.length > 3) {
          let prodSearched = this.apiService.searchProd(value);
          prodSearched.pipe(share()); // ADDED PIPE SHARE
          this.saveProdSearched(prodSearched);
          return prodSearched;
        } else {
          return of(null);
        }
      })
    );
  }
  //This function save the last result inside of an array of Product
  private saveProdSearched(prodSearched: Observable<Product[]>) {
    prodSearched.subscribe(items => {
      this.lastSearch = items
    })
  }
```

Comment: I very much doubt the same request is sent twice. My guess is that you're using CORS, and that you are thus seeing the standard pre-fetch OPTIONS request followed by the actual GET request.

Comment: Please check the headers section in the network tab and verify whether the 
Request Method is Get in both the cases

Comment: @JBNizet the backend is in NodeJS where I use a cors package. Without it I can't fetch my apis so is it possible to avoid this issue with cors bypass active on server side?

Comment: mind adding the code in which you call `searchProd`?

Comment: @FranklinPious both request methods are GET

Comment: Then it means the calling code is sending the request twice, probably by subscribing twice to your observable.

Comment: @Jota.Toledo see edit 2

Comment: @JBNizet may you find out where this happens looking at the code in the post? Thanks for your help

Comment: My guess is that you are using the `async` pipe on `searchResults` in two different places in your template. Try adding the `shareReplay(1)` operator call into your stream pipeline.

Comment: Please add the sections of your template where you bind `searchResults`

Comment: @Jota.Toledo done, see component.html in edit 2. Thanks for help

Comment: Are you binding `searchResults | async` to some variable anywhere else in the template? Are you manually subscribing `searchResults` in your component? Did `shareReplay(1)` had any effect? The interceptor code is fine, your stream pipe is fine. The `valueChanges` stream is correctly emitting single values. If it wasnt the case, all requests other than the last would be canceled because of the `switchMap`. So I agree with @JBNizet

Comment: You might want to add a `distinctUntilChanged` operator, at least to see if the valueChanges doesn't emit the same value twice

Comment: @Jota.Toledo the problem is with the function call `this.saveProdSearched(prodSearched)` inside the component.ts block. Because I subscribe to the prodSearched observable and so I fire another request but I don't know why. I have to mantain this behaviour in order to save the results for other purposes. How can I obtain the same without subscribing/launching the request again? I tried with  `prodSearched.pipe(share())` before passing it to the function but nothing changed.
I provide the code inside the edit2.

Comment: @JBNizet you was right! I subscribe inside the template and also inside the component.ts, but I still need these two subscription in order to save the result for other purposes, how can I avoid to send twice the request and maintain the current behaviour?

Comment: The easiest way is probably to not subscribe in the template: since the result is saved in the component, just display the result stored in the component.

Comment: @JBNizet thank you very much! I solved the issue, you saved me

Comment: simply add `shareReplay(1)` at the end of your `pipe` call

Comment: @Jota.Toledo I solved following JBNizet instruction, anyway thank you for your help and time spent on my issue!

Answer (score 2):

The problem was that I was subscribing twice. One in the function `this.saveProdSearched(prodSearched);` and one in the template with pipe `async`. I solved the issue simply saving the result of the `saveProdSearched()` function, removing the async pipe from template and displaying the result from an array of Product

Answer (score 0):

it happened to me too, but in my case i'm using `async` pipe on a same `Observable` returned by `HttpClient` on 2 different components's templates, so it's subscribing to the `Observable` twice, that's why it's intercepting the request twice in the `HttpInterceptor`.

You need to check if you're using `async` or .subscribe() on the same Observable 2 times (the `Observable` returned by `HttpClient`)